# Python/Discord Failure to write in files

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In the following code, the files are created and closed properly with no error messages but when it tries to write into the file, nothing happens. No error messages and no 0 written into the file:

```
if message.content == "MMO start":
    dir = r'C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\MMOProfiles'
    MessageAuthor = str(message.author)
    newpath = os.path.join(dir,MessageAuthor)
    doesExist = os.path.exists(newpath)
    if doesExist == False:
        await message.channel.send("Creating profile")
        os.makedirs(newpath,1)
        newpath = os.path.join(newpath,"Level.txt")
        open(newpath,"x")
        newpath.close()
        open(newpath,"w")
        newpath.write("0")
        newpath.close()
        
    if doesExist == True:
        await message.channel.send("You already have a profile")
```

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try putting `print(1)` statements after each `if` statement to make sure it's actually calling the code

Comment: Why don't you just use `file = open("Level.txt")`? and you don't have to do `if doesExist == False` or `==True`, you can do `if not doesExist` or `if doesExist`

Comment: What is `newpath.close`? You're trying to "close" a string, it will raise an error. You need to declare a file handler. `f = open(newpath)` and then close it with `f.close()`

Comment: If you didn't get an error, your program is not even entering the first `if` block.

Comment: one neat tip: You can replace "if boolean == True" with simply "if variable", and "if boolean == False" with "if not variable". When you have an if statement of a boolean expression, it executes if and only if that boolean is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newpath = os.path.join(newpath,"Level.txt")
type(newpath)
```

**str**

You are trying to write into a string, not into a file handler

do

```
    f = open(newpath,"w")
    f.write("0")
    f.close()
```